# Integrate separated standalone deployed websites into one website and show them with the same base URL

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-core, routes, azure-active-directory

I have several website projects which they already deployed in separate subdomains and also they have their specific resources and I want to create a launch/landing subdomain website in which I can reach to each website in different subdomains in this launching website's menu, without changing the subdomain and show them like they are internal routes. Also user needs to login separately in each of them through AzureAD login process. (DON'T want to use `iframe` cause as far as I know AzureAD doesn't allow it)

For example I have these websites:

```
sub1.example.com
sub2.example.com
sub3.example.com
```

And in my launch website `launch.example.com` user clicks the menu items (which are these three website's text) and I want to redirect to the requested website without changing the subdomain and the output should be like:

```
launch.example.com/sub1
launch.example.com/sub2
launch.example.com/sub3
```

Is this possible? If so what is the best practice for this situation?

Stack configuration:

- ASP.NET Core WebAPI
- C#
- Angular
- Azure Cloud
- Azure AD

Comment: Hi. This is not a Dotnet issue. You can have as many API's as you want. You just need to handle it in the DNS. Don't know where you host your dns or how that Setup looks.

Comment: Actually I don't want to have many API's, I want to have many websites in one website through one API. All of my websites and their relating resources are managing in one azure cloud including DNS zone, db, kubernetes etc

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, because every resource should have it's own domain or subdomain so the browser knows where to point. As you have it right now is the only proper way, when different subdomains respond for different applications. And yes iframe is always a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But isn't any way to just change the URL in frontend address bar, after calling for different domain or subdomain?

Comment: @masoud unfortunately no, you can't manipulate URL with javascript, but you can make use of a load balancer with configured URL path-based routing like Azure Application Gateway:
[Azure App Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/how-application-gateway-works)

Comment: You mean by using a load balancer and an Azure gateway and a launcher website, I can route the requests to different subdomains without returning the subdomain urls to the frontend?

Comment: Azure App Gateway is the load balancer itself, but there is a bunch of different gateway services like Azure has. Yes, the idea is that when the client sends a request the load balancer intercepts it and after parsing your URL path it knows to which server sends that request, and after the server returned response load balancer will send that response to the client as it was from itself.